# Get current store name in observer method

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, stores

I have created Two stores under two websites in my Magento installation

I have tried following code in my observer method,

```
$store = Mage::app()->getStore();        
$name = $store->getName();
```

but it is not giving me correct store name. It always show first store name while I am on the second store.

I am using **checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method** event

Comment: This must work as it should, also try `Mage::app()->getStore()->getFrontendName()`

Comment: Try this http://www.kathirvel.com/magento-get-current-store-id-code-name-status-details/

Comment: What are you observing? (assume it's a frontend action?)

Comment: Post the event name  you're observing.

Answer (score 0):

**For getting store details use**

```
$Store=Mage::app()->getGroup();
$Store->getName();
```

Comment: I am using Multi store, how can i get products using selected Store Id. Now code like -> https://justpaste.it/6fi1f. when i use this code its return all my products, how can i display only for selected store products?